# Using the LDS and LES instructions

Tags: assembly

So, i was given the following exercise ";Modify the content of two words from the memory, using their far ;addresses (32 bit address). Hint: use the LDS and LES instructions."

And when i run the code below, i get the following error: "Can't address with currently assumed segment registers". Could you please explain to me what does this error mean and how to write the program correctly?

```
_DATA SEGMENT PUBLIC 'DATA'
X   DW  10
Y   DW  15
ADR_X   DD  X
ADR_Y   DD  Y

_DATA ENDS

_CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'
ASSUME CS: _CODE

START   PROC    FAR

PUSH    DS
XOR AX, AX
MOV AX, _DATA  ; initializing the segment register
MOV DS, AX

LDS SI,ADR_X
LES DI,ADR_Y

MOV WORD PTR[SI],20
MOV WORD PTR ES:[DI],30

RET
START ENDP
_CODE ENDS

END START
```

Comment: It's been a while, but you probably need `ASSUME DS: _DATA` also for the unqualified `[SI]` reference to work. Other notes: setting up DS explicitly is redundant when you also do `LDS`, and then, you push DS but never pop it again.

Comment: LDS could be modifying DS before the LES instruction is exectuted (it doesn't in this case, but it's not a generic solution). Do the LES first, or you could move ADR_X and ADR_Y to after the ret so they are accessed using CS (the assembler should do a default CS override for you).

Answer (score 0):

Example microsoft style code meant for msdos or dos console windows that support 16 bit real mode

```
dgroup  group   _data,_bss,stack
_data   segment public 'data'
x       dw      10
y       dw      15
adr_x   dd      x
adr_y   dd      y
_data   ends
_bss    segment public 'bss'
_bss    ends
stack   segment stack 'stack'
        dw      2048 dup (?)            ; stack
stack   ends
_text   segment para public 'code'
        assume  cs:_text,ds:dgroup,es:nothing,ss:dgroup
start   proc    far
        mov     ax,_data                ; init ds
        mov     ds,ax
        les     di,adr_y                ; get addresses
        lds     si,adr_x
        mov     word ptr ds:[si],20     ; set values
        mov     word ptr es:[di],30
        mov     ax,04c00h               ; exit to dos
        int     21h
start   endp
_text   ends
        end     start
```